# Slow acceleration is working, but rapid acceleration is not

Tags: engine, toyota, corolla, maf

When I press the accelerator pedal slowly, the car normally accelerates, it does this in a good way, no lack power.
If I press the accelerator pedal all the way to the maximum in one rapid movement, it accelerates much worse than in the first case. It's the same when I try it while driving or in place.
The attached chart shows this difference in time, because both peaks were finished at 5500 rpm.

The first peak is a smooth acceleration, the second is the gas pressed quickly into the floor. I see that MAF sensor provide that the air flow is almost the same in both samples, but the thortle position is much diffrent. It's right or not?
I checked MAF sensor with ohmmeter, and it have 2,25 kOhm like they said in Toyota Owners Workshop Manual.
My car is Toyota Corolla 2001, 1.6VVTi 110hp.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this problem, it was trivial. Earlier user of this car drove not very dynamic and on low range of engine rpm. I thought that fuel injection map was incorrect, so I reseted ECU throught disconecting car battery for few minutes. After that everything works fine.